# IOS/Objective-C: Best way to clear ivars or property values in SharedInstanceSingleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I call a sharedInstance of a class to carry out certain tasks.  Some of the methods make use of properties. I am running into issues, however, of clearing these properties so they do not persist.

I gather there is no equivalent of life cycle methods in a shared instance so you cannot clear them on view did disappear.  And for that matter, ARC does not get rid of them.

Do you have to clear values one by one or is there any place in the class akin to view did disappear where you could put code once to clear all properties.

Comment: please share some code of your singleton class

Comment: If you find yourself needing to maintain state in a singleton, then perhaps you can refactor it out into a normal class to avoid this problem?

Comment: The code is very complicated which is why I was hoping to find a single place to clear all the values rather than have to catch every possible sequence. In various places, I say self.continuing = @3; or some other NSNumber.  I then try to reset it back to zero but with the complicated logic, on at least one occasion, it got stuck in @2.  This persisted even after i closed the view controller that called the instance and did numerous other things in the app as one would expect with the singleton.  The only way I could clear the value was to rebuild the app.

Comment: Why not add a "reset" method to the class. Have this method clear whatever ivars/properties you need.

Comment: It's not the problem of singleton class, it's the problem of your design which prevent you to reset your `ivar`. So, I suggest you to look into your code & trying to find the root cause of the problem, then fix it instead.

Comment: I took the reset approach and it did the job.